# Options for a Simple Inbound Notification Methods to Trigger some processes

Tags: apex-email-service, inboundservices

I have a dataloader process that pushes data into several different orgs. The process starts once a complex extract process has completed and created a set of files.

I'd like to change the process so that each org pulls the data into the org via a web process and runs a batch to process the data. I can envision how to do that using callouts and batches/queueable etc, but the once piece I am struggling with is how to tell each org the data is ready to retrieve...

I really don't want to store credentials for each org, since then I need a secure place to store them, passwords expire etc...so I'd like to find a way to send a non-authenticated notification to each org that can trigger the process. I am thinking the best way might be to have an inbound email handler that receives a notification, perhaps from only a specified address. But is there a better option? Setting up the email handlers right can be tricky in my experience, especially for less experienced admins.

I have thought maybe an anon apex class on a site - but then orgs have to set up sites which they may not want to do...and that can be just as complex for orgs...

Is there any other SF feature I am not considering?